# Wrap string with HTML before DOM Insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following if statement that returns a string :

```
var _title = ( data.complete.question ) ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect';
```

Is it possible to wrap this string with HTML before it is inserted into the DOM ? 
Something like :

```
// determine if correct or incorrect
var _title = ( data.complete.question ) ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect';

// wrap the returned string in a h2 tag, store this into a variable
// when ready 
// append to the DOM
```

Comment: what html do you want it wrapped with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("<div>").text(_title).appendTo(...
```

Comment: Thank you James. A very simple solution